# How can i create a new column in pyspark containing floating random numbers but i want to generate the same no always?

Tags: python, pyspark

I want create a new column in spark containing floating point random numbers but i want to generate the same output always i.e i want to use a fix seed value as 102101.

Comment: Random but same.....haha

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand

df.withColumn('RandomNumber', rand(seed=10))
```

Comment: i am doing this only and it is working fine but i am using jupyter notebook on aws by spinning up ec2 instance and whenever i create a new instance this rand() function will give different set of values.

Comment: Despite using seed?

Comment: yeah..and whenever someone else uses my code by spinning up other instance of ec2 server on aws on their own machine then the random numbers which got generated are different. is this a system glitch on aws?